# Define a template function taking a parameter of a template class

Tags: c++, templates

There is a template class

```cpp
template <class T0, class T1, ....... > // many template parameters
class Foo { ...... }
```

How can I define a template function to accept `Foo` with any template parameters?

The function can be `operator <<`, in which case defining a single template parameter would often break the compilation. C++ 11 solution is welcome.

Comment: Your use of the ellipsis (`...`)  is a bit unfortunate. Do you mean `Foo` to be a variadic `template` or just one with an arbitrary but fixed number of parameters?

Comment: @5gon12eder Edited... thanks!

Comment: Please post closer to actual code, what you have tried, what went wrong, *and* what your abstract goal is.  Pseudo code is a poor idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a function template like this:

```
template <typename ...Args>
void f(Foo<Args...> foo)
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: If this is what the OP meant to ask, I think it is the correct answer.

Answer (score 2):

The most obvious approach would be

```
template <typename... T>
std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, Foo<T...> const& value) {
    return out << "Foo(...)";
}
```

This version is more specialized than a version taking just one template argument. If you were to define this operator with just one template argument you'd need to determine the template actually does fit the definition of `Foo<T...>` and otherwise remove it from the overload set. Although this can be done, relying on partial ordering of overloads seems to be simpler in this case.