# How can I define a template operator inside a template class scope?

Tags: c++, templates

I have a problem with a matrix class that I am trying to "templatize". The idea is to be able to multiply two matrices of different type without explicitly overloading the multiplication methods. For instance let's say we have a `type A` and a `type B`. if I multiply a `matrix<A>` by a `matrix<B>` and if I know that multiplying elements `type A * type B` gives me a `type B` then `matrix<A>*matrix<B>` should give me a `matrix<B>` (I hope it is clear).

That being said I partially solved my problem with `std::common_type`. My code was behaving well until I tried to implement the *= operator (you'll see if you comment the *= related parts). Here is a simple code that allows to reproduce my current error :

```
#ifndef MATRICE_H
#define MATRICE_H

#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T1>
class Matrice
{
private:
    T1 table;

public:
    T1 getTable(){return table;}
    Matrice(T1 m_table);

    //template<typename T2>
    //Matrice<T1>& operator *= (Matrice<T2>&);
};

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
Matrice<T3> operator*(Matrice<T2>&, Matrice<T1>&);

template<typename T1, typename T2>
Matrice<T1>& Matrice<T1>::operator *= (const Matrice<T2>& B);

#endif
```

and the body :

```
#include "Matrice.h"

template<typename T1>
Matrice<T1>::Matrice(T1 m_table):table(m_table)
{
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
Matrice<typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type> operator * (Matrice<T2>& M2, Matrice<T1>& M1)
{   
    
    typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type tab3= (M1.getTable())*(M2.getTable());
    return Matrice<typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type>(tab3);
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
Matrice<T1>& Matrice<T1>::operator *= (const Matrice<T2>& B)
{
    table = (typename T1) table*(B.getTable())
}

int main()
{
    float tab1(12.5);
    int tab2(11);
    Matrice<float> M1(tab1);
    Matrice<int> M2(tab2);
    Matrice<float> M3 =  M1*M2;
    std::cout << M3.getTable() << std::endl;
    M3*=M2;
    return 0;
}
```

I get the following mirror errors which kinda feels like the god of c++ is trolling around :

```
Matrice.h:26:6: error: no declaration matches 'void Matrice<T1>::operator*=(Matrice<T2>&)'
   26 | void Matrice<T1>::operator *= (Matrice<T2>& B);

Matrice.cpp:18:6: error: no declaration matches 'void Matrice<T1>::operator*=(Matrice<T2>&)'
   18 | void Matrice<T1>::operator *= (Matrice<T2>& B)
```

and the obvious

```
Matrice.cpp: In function 'int main()':
Matrice.cpp:31:7: error: no match for 'operator*=' (operand types are 'Matrice<float>' and 'Matrice<int>')
   31 |     M3*=M2;
```

Remark : I've tried looking for these errors, I only saw vaguely related stuff that I mostly didn't understand. For instance here : [Define a template function taking a parameter of a template class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34278916/define-a-template-function-taking-a-parameter-of-a-template-class)
Please be gentle, this is my first template adventure!

additional question : is typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type evaluated everytime it shows up in the code or is the result somehow remembered? I might potentially multiply large matrices and I would like to avoid evaluating typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type thousands of times for a constant result.

EDIT : the exemple presented here is just a minimal code to reproduce the error

EDIT2 : the commented operator *= inside the class definition is just a trace of the various things I've tried so far to circumvent the error

Comment: Your commented out `operator*=` returns a `Matrice<T1>&`, while the operators you define have a `void` return type. (Additionally, they should all take their parameter as a const reference.)

Comment: Unrelated, but what is the point to have matrice consisting in a single element? Maybe it is for the MRE.

Comment: @NokiYola can you accept my answer below please? Thanks. You thanked me in the comments, but now your comments are gone, did you delete them?

Comment: @DavidBien I accepted. Sorry I didn't know that I could (nor had to) accept an answer. And no I did not delete my comments, I wonder how they disappeared.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You had some problems. The changes are self-explanatory I think. Let me know if not.
godbolt: https://godbolt.org/z/ErMdbfEnc

```
#include <typeinfo>
#include <type_traits>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T1>
class Matrice
{
private:
    T1 table;

public:
    const T1 & getTable() const
    {
        return table;
    }
    T1 & getTable()
    {
        return table;
    }
    Matrice(T1 m_table);

    template<typename T2>
    Matrice<T1>& operator *= ( const Matrice<T2>& );
};

template<typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
Matrice<T3> operator*(Matrice<T2>&, Matrice<T1>&);

// template<typename T1>
// template<typename T2>
// Matrice<T1>& Matrice<T1>::operator *= (const Matrice<T2>& B);

template<typename T1>
Matrice<T1>::Matrice(T1 m_table):table(m_table)
{
}

template<typename T1, typename T2>
Matrice<typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type> operator * (Matrice<T2>& M2, Matrice<T1>& M1)
{   
    
    typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type tab3= (M1.getTable())*(M2.getTable());
    return Matrice<typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type>(tab3);
}

template<typename T1>
template<typename T2>
Matrice<T1>& Matrice<T1>::operator *= (const Matrice<T2>& B)
{
    table = (T1) table*(B.getTable());
    return *this;
}

int main()
{
    float tab1(12.5);
    int tab2(11);
    Matrice<float> M1(tab1);
    Matrice<int> M2(tab2);
    Matrice<float> M3 =  M1*M2;
    std::cout << M3.getTable() << std::endl;
    M3*=M2;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I was thanking you in my previous comment but I was also asking if you knew if `typename std::common_type<T1,T2>::type` would be evaluated at every iteration in a for loop. I also asked for precision in the modifications you brought (in particular the first `const` of `const T1 & getTable() const` and the difference between `template<typename T1>
template<typename T2>` and `template<typename T1, typename T2>`)